# Can't update the text of a article with javascript, only the title

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, replace

Im trying to replace a news article every 5 minutes. I fetch the articles with pytho(flask) and then I render a template with multiple list of article title, article text, article image.

Now can get the title to switch every 5 minutes but for some reason the text won't change after the interval. It just does nothing. I tried so much, and I just can't figure out what is the problem.

Code:

```js
var text = ["{{artikel_titel[0]}}", "{{artikel_titel[1]}}", "{{artikel_titel[2]}}"];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("titel");
var inst = setInterval(change, 5000);

function change() {
  $("#titel").text(text[counter]);
  counter++;
  if (counter >= text.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=newsarticle_container>
  <h1 id='titel'>{{artikel_titel}}</h1>
  <img id=plaatje src="{{topimage}}">
  <div id='tekst'>{{artikel_tekst}}</div>
</div>
```

So this one works for chaning the titles but as soon I use {{artikel_tekst[0]}} it just doesn't work. It looks like the text is too big to be updated. I also tried with elem.innnerHTML. (I haven't tried to replace the image yet).

Hopefully someone can help me out updating the article. I'm so confused why it's not working. If any questions,feel free to ask!

Comment: Are `artikel_titel` and `artikel_tekst` arrays?

Comment: Your code works. What's the issue?

Comment: This `$("#titel").text(text[counter]);` replaces the title, if you need to replace the text as well then you need a similar call but with `$("#tekst").text(_something_);`

Comment: artikel_titel and artikel_tekst are arrays made in flask. Now the title switching works but as soon as I try it with the {{artikel_tekst}}. Nothing happens. Is there a limit you can pass into innerHTMLor .text?

Comment: Can you output the content of your artikel_tekst variable here?  Or any debugging info from the javascript console?